# What is does (0 & 1) do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking through the source of a library I'm working with, and I found something I haven't seen before.

```
$(item).each(function(child) {
        oddEven = (i & 1);
        targetNode.append(jasper_build_product(this,oddEven));
        i++;
    });
```

Notice the `oddEven = (i & 1);`. What does the `(i & 1)` part do? I'm particularly curious about the ampersand.

Comment: @AD7six not a duplicate, IMHO

Comment: For reference: [Bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND)

Comment: @Alnitak I'm interested as to your reasoning given the question is what the & means, not necessarily how that determines odd/even (which understanding & answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` operator is a bitwise `AND`, and more specifically the expression `x & 1` returns the least significant bit (LSB) of the value `x`.

Since the internal representation of numbers is base-2, an LSB of 1 indicates an odd value, and 0 indicates an even value.

Comment: Less technically: `0b0001 & 0b0001` yields 1 (`0b0001` is the binary representation of 1) and `0b0001 & 0b0010` yields 0 (`0b0010` is the binary representation of 2)

Comment: @LUH3417 I'm not sure I agree that this is "less technical" :p

Comment: OK, agreed - it's just a different representation of a complicated issue